# listar post com foto de um blog wordpress em um site php

Tags: php, wordpress

Gostaria de listar post aletorio com foto, ou por categoria mas em outro site.
tipo pego de um blog em wordpress e coloco em um site php, como eu tenho uns 4 blogs faria isso de cada um, criando um agregador de post direto dos blogs

Answer (score 1):

Evandro,

com a chegada da [WP REST API](http://v2.wp-api.org/) (que inclusive já está em sua segunda versão), agora é possível obter conteúdo de outros sites em WordPress para exibi-los em alguma aplicação que interprete essas informações em formato JSON.

Como não conheço um plugin/ferramenta pronta para disponibilizar exatamente isso que você procura, vou indicar [este link](https://css-tricks.com/using-the-wp-api-to-fetch-posts/) para que você entenda como chegar na solução da sua demanda (apesar de ser em inglês, esse tutorial irá cobrir os prontos essenciais que você procura).

Abraços!

Comment: é bem interessante, porem procuro algo fora do wpress, eu quero capitar o post do wpress e colocar o resultado em uma plataforma php

Comment: Mas o que ele falou é exatamente "fora do WordPress", uma vez que com a API funcionando, basta fazer um requisição "em uma plataforma php".

Comment: eu consegui entender um pokin, instalei o plugin,porem a tal pasta wp-json nao existe em meu server, tem noção como posso resolver? da essa resposta --> file_get_contents(http://fotoshot.net/wp-json/posts?filter[posts_per_page]=4): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!